# upload image in s3 using byte array

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

Hi I want to upload image in s3, I have byte array.
How i can convert byte array to a temporary url on the fly?

```
$byte_arr = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAhCAYAAAHL1En6AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAK
T2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AU
kSYqIQkQSogh';

    //$file_content = 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $byte_arr';
    //echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $byte_arr' />";die;
    $s3->putBucket("bucketname", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
    $fileName = 'user_1.jpg';
    //move the file
    if ($s3->putObjectFile($file, "bucketname", $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
        echo "We successfully uploaded your file.";
    }else{
        echo "Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.";
    }
```

so my question is how to get $file from byte array. I need tmp_url for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function:

```
 $data = base64_decode($byte_arr);
 $formImage = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

Comment: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: Resource id #43
this error is giving when i have put $formImage in
if ($s3->putObjectFile($formImage, "bucketname", $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))

Comment: Using imagecreatefromstring() you can convert string to image, now what you want to do is, save that image somewhere and give that path to $s3->putObjectFile()

Comment: is it necessary to save this image somewhere can I not get image url on the fly without saving image?